# What is "double universe point" in Ultimate Frisbee?

Tags: terminology, ultimate-frisbee

The sport of Ultimate has many strange terms. One of them is "[universe point](https://web.archive.org/web/20160621035506/http://www.examiner.com/article/frisbee-101-what-is-universe-point)".

But what is "*double* universe point", apparently happening at the end of [this game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zO2KXjAk5Q)?

Comment: @OlaStröm I see that [after your edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/revisions/8869/3) with the edit summary "Fixed broken link" the first link was pointing back to this question - I assume that wasn't the intention. I have included a [Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160621035506/http://www.examiner.com/article/frisbee-101-what-is-universe-point) instead - maybe you head some better choice of link in mind.

Comment: I guess the intention was probably to include a link to this question: [In Ultimate Frisbee, what is 'universe point'?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1599)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, it's just a misnomer, probably from combining "double game point" and "universe point". There isn't really any interesting variation on universe point that one might meaningfully label "double".

Comment: +1.  A universe point is simply a double game point, which is what it is called when each team is one point away from winning, and the game ends on the next point scored.